# Selecting an aggregate schedule for several resources in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm currently building a schedule in PostgreSQL, 
and I've run up against a wall because of my rusty SQL skills.

So, I have a table with bookings for different resources, like

```
 startTime | endTime   | resource 
 ---------------------------------
 TIMESTAMP | TIMESTAMP | INTEGER
```

Selecting all the bookings for a resource in a given time period
(such as in a week) is easy, just

```
select "startTime", "endTime", "resource"    
from bookings 
where "resource" = 4 
AND "start" 
  BETWEEN '2014-01-05 23:00:00.000 +00:00' 
  AND '2014-01-10 23:00:00.000 +00:00';
```

Then I can just present the schedule for that week for the given resource.

Likewise, selecting the bookings for several resources is just

```
select "startTime", "endTime", "resource"    
from bookings 
where "resource" IN (1,2,5) 
AND "start" 
  BETWEEN '2014-01-05 23:00:00.000 +00:00' 
  AND '2014-01-10 23:00:00.000 +00:00';
```

However, I'd also be able to select an agggregate schedule for a set of resources, so that it only shows bookings where the the time ranges for bookings in all the given resources overlap. The number of resources would most probably not exceed 100.

So, for this example data:

```
       startTime        |        endTime         | resource 
------------------------+------------------------+----------
 2014-01-08 08:00:00+01 | 2014-01-08 09:30:00+01 |        1
 2014-01-08 06:00:00+01 | 2014-01-08 09:00:00+01 |        2
 2014-01-08 07:30:00+01 | 2014-01-08 15:30:00+01 |        5
 2014-01-08 11:00:00+01 | 2014-01-08 11:30:00+01 |        1
 2014-01-08 11:00:00+01 | 2014-01-08 11:30:00+01 |        2
```

Id like to write a query that would only return the times where all three resources are tied up, something like

```
select "startTime", "endTime"    
from ????
where "resource" IN (1,2,5) 
AND ???
???
```

Which, for the example data above would return only

```
       startTime        |        endTime         
------------------------+------------------------
 2014-01-08 08:00:00+01 | 2014-01-08 09:00:00+01 
 2014-01-08 11:00:00+01 | 2014-01-08 11:30:00+01
```

Note that there might be "gaps" in the set of resources, and that the query should return nothing when not all of the resources are booked.

Does anyone have a good idea on how to implement this?

I've looked into doing it using range types in Postgres, (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/rangetypes.html) but not really come up with any solution.

EDIT: Fixed my erroneous example return data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query assumes that resources are numbered without gaps, beginning from 1 to N:

```
WITH RECURSIVE T( startTime, endTime, resource ) AS(
  SELECT * FROM table1
  WHERE resource = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT greatest( t1.startTime, t.startTime ) startTime,
         least( t1.endTime, t.endTime ),
         t1.resource
  FROM T
  JOIN table1 t1 
  ON t.resource + 1 = t1.resource
      AND (t.startTime, t.endTime) OVERLAPS (t1.startTime, t1.endTime) 
)
SELECT startTime, EndTime FROM t
WHERE resource = (SELECT max(Resource) FROM table1);
```

Demo:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0b4e9/7/0

Results:

```
|                      STARTTIME |                        ENDTIME |
|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|
| January, 08 2014 11:00:00+0000 | January, 08 2014 11:30:00+0000 |
| January, 08 2014 08:00:00+0000 | January, 08 2014 09:00:00+0000 |
```

---

Below is a demo for a case when resources are not numbered, and we want to filter then (run the query only on a subset of resources):
Demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/82f36/15/0

Notice that `resources` column in this demo is of a varchar type, not a number.
This query traverses resources in reverse order (from top to bottom) - the final result is the same.

```
WITH RECURSIVE  src AS(
 SELECT *
 FROM table1
  -- some condition to filter only needed resources from the table
 WHERE resource BETWEEN 'resource 11' AND 'resource 33'
),
src1 AS(
  -- this join calculates numbers `nbr`
  SELECT * 
  FROM src
  JOIN (
    SELECT resource,
           row_number() OVER (order by resource) nbr
    FROM(
       SELECT distinct resource
      FROM src
    ) q1
  )q2
  ON src.resource = q2.resource
),
-- main query
T( startTime, endTime, nbr ) AS(

  SELECT startTime, endTime, nbr FROM src1
  WHERE nbr = (SELECT max(nbr) FROM src1)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT greatest( t1.startTime, t.startTime ) startTime,
         least( t1.endTime, t.endTime ),
         t1.nbr
  FROM T
  JOIN src1 t1 
  ON t.nbr - 1 = t1.nbr
     AND (t.startTime, t.endTime) OVERLAPS (t1.startTime, t1.endTime)
)
SELECT startTime, EndTime FROM t
WHERE nbr = 1;
```

Comment: I appreciate the subtle way you pointed out the error in my example ;)  Didn't know about the WITH RECURSIVE clause at all.

Comment: However, resources will not start at 1, and will not run through all available resources, but that should be a simple fix. Thanks!

Comment: I've appended an example that shows how to filter only required records, and how to cope with resources that don't start from 1 - resources in this demo are not even numbers

Comment: Thanks again, I'll just do some testing and adjust the answer for my specific case before I accept. Really appreciate the effort you've put in!

Comment: Hmmm, just realized that this statement fails if only one of the resources is booked. Then it will make a union with itself, and erroneously return an overlap...

Comment: `Resource is booked` - I guess that the table contains some additional column `booked=yes/no`. If yes, then just add an additional condition `WHERE booked<>yes` to the query.

Comment: Using an extra condition to see if there are any free resources (completely unbooked) solved the problem. However, with the comparison in your query you get edge overlaps (i.e. bookings 0s long), using the OVERLAPS operator fixes that.

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

        -- Table
CREATE TABLE bookings
        ( startTime timestamp NOT NULL
        , endTime timestamp NOT NULL
        , resource INTEGER NOT NULL
        , PRIMARY KEY (resource, startTime, endTime)
        );

        -- pupulate it
INSERT INTO bookings( startTime, endTime, resource ) VALUES
 ('2014-01-08 08:00:00+01','2014-01-08 09:30:00+01',        1)
 , ('2014-01-08 06:00:00+01','2014-01-08 09:00:00+01',        2)
 , ('2014-01-08 07:30:00+01','2014-01-08 15:30:00+01',        3)
 , ('2014-01-08 11:00:00+01','2014-01-08 11:30:00+01',        1)
 , ('2014-01-08 11:00:00+01','2014-01-08 11:30:00+01',        2)
        ;

SELECT GREATEST (a.startTime,b.startTime,c.startTime) AS startTime
        , LEAST (a.endTime,b.endTime,c.endTime) AS endTime
FROM bookings a
JOIN bookings b ON b.resource = 2 AND (a.startTime, a.endTime) OVERLAPS (b.startTime, b.endTime)
JOIN bookings c ON c.resource = 3 AND (a.startTime, a.endTime) OVERLAPS (c.startTime, c.endTime)
WHERE a.resource = 1
        ;
```

RESULTS:

```
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 5
      starttime      |       endtime       
---------------------+---------------------
 2014-01-08 08:00:00 | 2014-01-08 09:00:00
 2014-01-08 11:00:00 | 2014-01-08 11:30:00
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up accepting @kordirko's answer, but I'm grateful for your help too.